# Why can't I reference sites, then copy and paste to answer questions?

Tags: discussion

If I reference a website - no plagiarism! - what's wrong with copy and paste if enough to answer question?

If I copy and paste a book, would my answer get deleted too?

https://money.stackexchange.com/a/35492 mostly copy and paste.

Comment: Using a post from six years ago as evidence of suggested practise is not advisable.

Answer (score 7):

This is clearly documented in the [Help Center](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing):

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.

If you don't have any significant content to add on top of limited quoting from an external source, StackExchange is not the site for you.

Answer (score -1):

One should be able to reference sites, then copy and paste to answer questions. There is no point in paraphrasing a referenced quote if it answers the question.

As [GS - Apologise to Monica♦](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/366/gs-apologise-to-monica) says, the [Help Center](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) mentions:

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.

Two remarks:

1. The quote only mentions the case where one copies the "**complete** text of external sources".
2. "instead, use their words and ideas to support your own." makes no sense when the question is looking for some objective answer, which is often the case on https://money.stackexchange.com/: the answerer typically doesn't have any "own" words or ideas, they're is reporting some objective answer. Also that sounds like some homework instructions for primary school.