# Advice needed on asking question about stock splits

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

#### Background

I posted a question that was not well-received: [When am I entitled to participate in a stock split? — record date, split date, ex date](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/129819)

Shortly after posting the question above, I posted a second question: [How is the "record date" relevant in stock splits?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/129824). This question was also poorly received, and was quickly closed as a duplicate of the first. (Note - also deleted by its author. /JTP)

In the meantime, I tried to read as much about stock splits as possible. I learned much that I did not know about when I posted those questions. With hindsight, I agree with the assessment of a user who said that the first question was "overly complicated" and "jibber jabber about pay date, ex date, record date and comparison with stock and cash dividends". I now understand what the "pre-split" price is, and when stocks start to trade at a "post-split" price.

However, even after spending more time learning about stock splits, I still do not understand the "record date". The answer to the first question does not mention anything about the "record date". I also believe that future answers are unlikely to address the "record date" due to other glaring problems in the first question. This leads me to believe that the second question is not a duplicate of the first. I have since edited the second question to hopefully emphasize its relevance to personal finance.

#### I need advice

Current situation:

- The two questions I asked about stock splits were poorly received (I now see why, at least for the first one)
- I want to ask a question specifically about the meaning of the "record date".

What should I do now? To the best of my ability, I want to avoid posting further "nonsense". Should I post a new question that essentially repeats the second question? Will the moderators consider reopening the second question? Or are such questions unsuitable for this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions are not bad questions. They are about a subject that a lot of people wonder about. I think some reviewers were making weird assumptions about your motives (looking for a way to scam the system), and the only answer to your first question essentially says, “It just works; don’t worry about it,” which of course is not a very satisfying answer.

That having been said, your first question does ask about the record date specifically, so the second question does appear to be essentially a duplicate to me.

I think you need to be patient with your first question. Yes, you got a downvote and some rude comments, but you got some upvotes, too. You left a comment on the lone answer asking for more information, which is appropriate. And more enlightening answers could be added at anytime.

Comment: Thanks. I will move some of the explanatory material from the duplicate question into the first.

Comment: Ben, are you able to see the posted, then deleted, answer, by Morrison? It's a cut/paste from the Apple FAQ, but, effectively answers the question, it seems to me. If you can see it, let me know if it's worth reopening.  (And yes, to both of you, I acknowledge, mine was a non-answer. Addressing your assumptions as true, confirmed by the other recent question [How does stock split work in practice with short sellers?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/129815/how-does-stock-split-work-in-practice-with-short-sellers) which Flux answered. )

Comment: Further, I'm abstaining from the reopen voting. I think we agree it's a dup, I'll let members decide if should be reopened. (I hit 'skip')

Comment: @JTP I’m not sure what you are asking me with your second comment. I see two deleted answers on the first question, which is already open. The answers were deleted by the authors. I have no idea why those two deleted their own posts, but if you are asking me whether or not you should undelete an answer that an author has deleted, I would say no.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica rephrasing - Does Morrison's answer address the question to your satisfaction? Anyone can repost that public information if it's helpful to the question.

Comment: @JTP Would that type of answer be acceptable to GS per https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2858/10997 ? I wonder if Morrison deleted his answer after reading that. It would be unfortunate.

Comment: I see.  It seems chepner already posted, with excellent mix of quote and his own explanation. Hopefully, flux feels that answer is sufficient.

Comment: @JTP And thank you for using the “Skip” button. In my opinion, the “Leave Closed” button should rarely, if ever, be used by a mod, as it removes the question instantly from the review queue.

Comment: NP. You taught me this. Like a 'vote to close', a mod vote to 'leave closed' is a full removal.  Since you pointed this out, I've tried to be careful.

Comment: Thank you for the assurance. I really appreciate it.